# How to make automatic editing of a phone number?

Tags: php, yii

There is a field, and it entered a phone number, how to make that automatically edited visual the phone number you type in the field, like this:
Im input in the field

```
89008991212
```

im geting automatic

```
8900-899-1212
```

Comment: Your question is unclear, do you mean that the input field should update as the user is entering the number? Or that the number should be formatted when shown on the site after it has been stored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the easiest would be to use some plugin for that, e.g. this one:

http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the preg_replace function: http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-replace.php

It allows you to match any regex pattern and replace it as you wish, for example, replace the first for digits with the same four digits + a dash.